# how to xor binary with python

Tags: python, binary, xor

I'm trying to xor 2 binaries using python like this but my output is not in binary
any help?

```
a = "11011111101100110110011001011101000"
b = "11001011101100111000011100001100001"
y = int(a) ^ int(b)
print y
```

Comment: Print in binary format, it should work

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
a="11011111101100110110011001011101000"
b="11001011101100111000011100001100001"
y=int(a,2) ^ int(b,2)
print('{0:b}'.format(y))
```

Comment: It don't give me the answer with the same length

Comment: If you want the answer to print with the same length, try: `print '{0:0{1}b}'.format(y,len(a))`

Comment: now it's working
what was the last thing because xor table should be like this
a = 1 and b = 1 output= 0
a = 0 and b = 0 output= 0
a = 0 and b = 1 output= 1
a = 1 and b = 0 output= 1

Comment: please think about update it with a python 3 version compatible, since python 2.x is mostly not supported anymore.

Answer (score 10):

To get the Xor'd binary to the same length, as per the OP's request, do the following:

```
a = "11011111101100110110011001011101000"
b = "11001011101100111000011100001100001"
y = int(a, 2)^int(b,2)
print bin(y)[2:].zfill(len(a))

[output: 00010100000000001110000101010001001]
```

Convert the binary strings to an integer base 2, then `XOR`, then `bin()` and then skip the first two characters, `0b`, hence the `bin(y0)[2:]`.
After that, just `zfill` to the length - `len(a)`, for this case.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to carryout XOR on the same length binaries, the following should work just fine:

```
c=[str(int(a[i])^int(b[i])) for i in range(len(a))]
c=''.join(c)
```

You can avoid the formatting altogether.

Answer (score -2):

Since you are starting with strings and want a string result, you may find this interesting but it only works if they are the same length.

```
y = ''.join('0' if i == j else '1' for i, j in zip(a,b))
```

If they might be different lengths you can do:

```
y = ''.join('0' if i == j else '1' for i, j in zip(a[::-1],b[::-1])[::-1])
y = a[len(y):] + b[len(y):] + y
```