# How to XOR two binary strings in python

Tags: python, xor

I need to do XOR operation between two binary strings.

```
xor("00110011", "11001100") = "11111111"
```

i am currently using this function

```
def xor(x, y):
    ans = ""
    for i in xrange(len(x)):
        if x[i] == "0" and y[i] == "1" or x[i] == "1" and y[i] == "0":
            ans += "1"
        else:
            ans += "0"
    return ans
```

please give me good method

Comment: You can use parenthesis, if you like. BTW, is there a specific problem in this code?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include a sample of your input and the expected output.

Comment: you can use `^` - the xor operator. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414093/how-to-xor-binary-with-python

Comment: If you are using Python 3, these are not binary strings in the Python sense.

Comment: You need to tell us about edge-cases too. What happens with with `xor('01', '00')` for example? Is the output `'1'` or `'01'`. In other words, should the output be *the same string length, always*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you *must* use strings of `'0'` and `'1'` characters, just use a mapping:

```
_xormap = {('0', '1'): '1', ('1', '0'): '1', ('1', '1'): '0', ('0', '0'): '0'}
def xor(x, y):
    return ''.join([_xormap[a, b] for a, b in zip(x, y)])
```

otherwise, just convert to two integers, XOR those and re-format back to a binary string:

```
def xor(x, y):
    return '{1:0{0}b}'.format(len(x), int(x, 2) ^ int(y, 2))
```

This ensures that the resulting string has the same length by zero-padding to the length of `x`.

Answer (score 4):

```
def xor(x, y):
    return '{0:b}'.format(int(x, 2) ^ int(y, 2))
```

Credits to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414093/how-to-xor-binary-with-python). Contrary to popular belief, [Python does have bitwise operators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators).

Comment: Note that this can lead to a *shorter* binary string, the null-padding is lost. Try it with `xor('00000001', '00000000')` for example.

Answer (score -2):

If you need to reinvent the whell

```
def alternative_xor(x, y):
  a = int(x)
  b = int(y)  
  return (a & ~b) | (~a & b)
```

Comment: The return value must be a string too. But why so circumspect about using `^`?

Comment: In addition: I like your use of the map! ^_^