# "Unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'str' and 'str'" with Binary in Python 3.x

Tags: python, string, integer, binary-operators

I'm currently doing a project on binary operators. Right now I have two lists with series of strings with 8 bits of 1s and 0s. Let's say I have this code (a representation of what is produced when I create the two arrays):

```
arr1 = ['0b01110101', '0b00001111', '0b01001101']
arr2 = ['0b10010100', '0b00000101', '0b00111001']
arr3 = []
```

I want to run a loop where I perform the XOR binary operator on each value. Here's my loop so far:

```
for i in len(arr1):
    arr3[i] = arr1[i] ^ arr2[i]
```

When I run this code I get this error message:

```
Unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'str' and 'str'
```

I've tried doing this:

```
arr3[i] = bin(arr1[i]) ^ bin(arr2[i])
```

and it returns this error message:

```
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

How would I get around this?

EDIT 1: This isn't a duplicate of what it has been flagged as in the comments. I'm not looking how to do a normal XOR binary function. I know how to do that. I'm looking for a way to convert these strings to binary numbers so that I can use the XOR operator on them.

Comment: cast them to ints.  `int('0b00111001', 2) == 57`.  All the bitwise operators work for ints.

Comment: Have you read these two answers to see if it helps answer your question: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414093/how-to-xor-binary-with-python) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612720/how-to-do-bitwise-exclusive-or-of-two-strings-in-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to xor binary with python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414093/how-to-xor-binary-with-python)

Comment: if you "unquote" the lists (arr1, arr2...) should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
arr1 = ['0b01110101', '0b00001111', '0b01001101']
arr2 = ['0b10010100', '0b00000101', '0b00111001']
arr3 = []

for i, _ in enumerate(arr1):
    xor = int(arr1[i], 2) ^ int(arr2[i], 2)
    arr3.append("0b{0:08b}".format(xor))
```

Output:

```
['0b11100001', '0b00001010', '0b01110100']
```

Comment: consider zipping the lists to avoid indexed access: `for a1,a2 in zip(arr1,arr2):`. otherwise good.

Answer (score 0):

`bin` is a string representation of the integer. You cannot XOR strings.

Just do an integer conversion, base 2, the conversion understands the integer, with `0b` or without it:

```
for a1,a2 in zip(arr1,arr2):
    print(bin(int(a1,2) ^ int(a2,2)))
```

result:

```
0b11100001
0b1010
0b1110100
```

Comment: Can you explain how this works? Such as why the second one shows up as only 4 bits long rather than a full 8 bits?

Comment: that's because of the format and the small number size. As another answer states, `"0b{0:08b}"` is the format that adds zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

You could unquote the lists

```
arr1 = ['0b01110101', '0b00001111', '0b01001101']
arr2 = ['0b10010100', '0b00000101', '0b00111001']
arr3 = []
```

And also fix an error on the loop and use `append` and `range` for iterations.

```
for i in range(len(arr1)):       # xrange for Pyhon2
    arr3.append(int(arr1[i], 2) ^ int(arr2[i], 2))
```

Comment: I can't actually unquote the lists. From the way that I generate them using my loop, they show up in the lists with quotes around them.

Comment: Cast each as Jean-François Fabre said and fix the loop, will modify the answer anyway to fit this new requirement.