# XOR in Python, SyntaxError, why?

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, xor

```
>>> x = 1101 ^ 0111
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    x = 1101 ^ 0111
                  ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid token

Why am I getting this syntax error in python? I see online that, "^ Bitwise Exclusive XOR
Description
Returns the result of bitwise XOR of two integers.

Syntax
A ^ B

A
Integer object.
B
Integer object."

So I think I am using two integers.

Comment: `0111` is not a valid integer literal. What did you intend to create?

Answer (score 3):

are `1101` and `0111` supposed to be bits? To represent bit literals, you should use `0b1101` and `0b0111`, because otherwise those are integers (and ints can't start with a `0`

Comment: Well, they are still `int` objects

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga true, that was a bit imprecise.

Comment: @AdamSmith I don't know if that pun was intentional but it was hilarious either way!

Answer (score 1):

First, you cannot use integers in such a way. Here is the error I got when I ran your code:

```
SyntaxError: leading zeros in decimal integer literals are not permitted;
use an 0o prefix for octal integers
```

In other words, you can't give Python an integer that starts with a zero. That used to work in Python 2 but is no longer supported in Python 3. (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/11620174/7583007)

I am assuming you are trying to use binary numbers? If so, you should try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19414115/7583007

Comment: You can specify binary literals in Python3 (and Python2) with a leading `0b`. `assert 0b111 == 7`

Answer (score 1):

I believe you wanted:

```
0b1101 ^ 0b0111
```

In general, the error you are receiving is because you placed a "0" in front of a number, something that python doesn't allow. The same would happen if you tried to do:

```
078
```

The start of a number beginning with zero, typically is special python code that indicates you will be providing a binary number, octal number, or hexidecimal number, which begin with 0b, 0o, or 0x, respectively.